# MS Access - Two lookups in one combobox depending on another text box

Tags: ms-access, combobox

First time post, if anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have a combo box have two lookup lists based on another text box.

So if a text box is populated A then than have the combobox show one list and if the text box is populated B then have the same combobox show another list.

If it's not possible, any suggestions for a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: This is called 'cascading' or dependent combobox (or listbox). Common topic, search forum or Google.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed.